# Trying to use wait() in java Process Builder

Tags: java, user-interface, cmd, processbuilder

Using process builder in java but I want the program to wait while the process is finished.

I tried to use pb.wait() but it keeps on waiting. How do I wait till all the commands have finished executing?

This is a very small part of my code.

```
String[] commands = {All my commands go here};
                    String command = "cmd.exe /c " + String.join(" && ", commands);
                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
                    pb.inheritIO(); 
                    try {
                        pb.start();
                        try {
                            pb.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error, Could not run.");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `wait()` method you called does not do what you expect (check javadoc for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long))

You want to wait for the process you started:

```
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```

see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()

Comment: Whenever I see people use `waitFor()`, I need to post this old but still relevant article: https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html. It could be updated to use `ProcessBuilder`, as using `redirectErrorStream(true)` removes the need to use two threads for reading. Instead, the contents can simply be read from the main application _before_ calling `waitFor()` (which technically may be unnecessary).

Comment: The use of `inheritIO()` probably makes it unnecessary to read from the streams though.

Comment: How do I wait till all the commands have finished executing? @asbachb

Comment: When you chain them with `&&` the program should wait until the last one finished.